# how to call css and js files in webview?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I have one local html page in my android app.
in html page i call css and js files but when i run app , only context loaded and css and js don't load

I import css and js folders to `android_assets/images/css nad android_assets/images/js`
and i call css and js in html page like this:

```
    <link href="./android_asset/images/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./android_asset/images/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./android_asset/images/css/touchnswipe.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="./android_asset/images/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="./android_asset/images/js/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./android_asset/images/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./android_asset/images/js/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./android_asset/images/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="./android_asset/images/js/jquery.hammer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./android_asset/images/js/TweenMax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./android_asset/images/js/responsive_example.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And in `Sites.java` onCreate section i write this code:

```
  WebView wbSites =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wbSites);
 //  wbSites.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
  // wbSites.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
   wbSites.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   wbSites.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/images/sites.html");
```

Tip: htmlpage named sites.html and pasted in `android_asset/images` path 
but still don't load js and css files.

pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it
i most write address like this

```
<script src="./js/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

. Refers to local root => `/android_asset/images/`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the `file://` prefixes to all the resources you want to load?

Comment: tried 'file://android_asset' and 'file:///android_asset' Like this : <script scr="file://android_asset/images/js/responsive_example.min.js " type="text/javascript"/> but still Do not work

Comment: For the sake of removing as many potential pitfalls as possible, have you tried moving the files simply to the `android_asset` folder? Also, I presume it's just typos, but you've used `android_asset` and `android_assets` interchangeably in your question- is there any chance this is the issue?